# Can I use `??` (Null coalescing operator) instead of empty?

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator

I have lots of code like this

```php
$Var = !empty($Data->title) ? ' string1 ' . $Data->title : ' string2 ' . $Var2;
```

I searched on the web and I found `?? (Null coalescing operator)`

Because of that, I assume can do something like this

```php
$Var = ' string1 ' . $Data->title ?? ' string2 ' . $Var2;
```

I asked that because I know `??` is used for `isset()` or `NULL` but I need `empty()` for my project code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already said

```
$a ?? $b
```

is a short hand for `(isset($a)) ? $a : $b;`

But the function [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns false if a variable was not defined, or if it was defined as null. Whereas [`!empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)  returns FALSE if var was not defined or has a empty or non-zero value. So you can't use `??` for `!empty()`.

You could use

```
$a ?: $b
```

which is a shorthand for

```
((bool)$a) ? $a : $b;
```

[Here are the rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) how a variable is casted to a Boolean.

In short `((bool)$a) == (!empty($a))` is always true, except if `$a` is a SimpleXML object created from empty tags.

However, in your case, neither `?:` nor `??` will work, because `' string1 ' . $Data->title` is always non-empty and defined.